# Setting up reducers in Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm setting up very basic Ngrx state management.

```
# app.module
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```

This code is generated with the Ngrx schematics generators.

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  [fromFilter.filterFeatureKey]: fromFilter.reducer
};
```

Which gives me the error

```
Expression form not supported in 'reducers'
```

I've tried this which I found on the Ngrx github page. This doesn't give any errors but just silently doesn't work, no state is generated.

```
export function reducers(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers(_reducers)(state, action);
}
```

I can get it to work by hard-coding the filter key, however that is not the recommended practice according to the docs.

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  filter: fromFilter.reducer
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with auto-generated code by the schematics right now. To keep the non-hardcoded dictionary version, use an injection token in your `app.module.ts`, like so (`reducers` and `State` are imported from your declaration):

```js
export const REDUCER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<State>>('root reducer');
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        StoreModule.forRoot(REDUCER_TOKEN),
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: REDUCER_TOKEN, useValue: reducers }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem only occurs when using ahead-of-time compilation, but since that's the default for most production builds, you have to use a token to get it to work.

Comment: Well, it's a bit sad that this work-around is needed, but it still works. This issue is quite old on their github page, strange that it isn't solved, or at least documented better.